# how to format my discord python bot output?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, tabulate

I am making a Disord bot based on a python code. The python code is executing perfectly. But when the discord bot calls the program it screws up the formatting/alignment of the output.

I am using tabulate on python for the output. Thankful for any help you can do to sort this out.

Here is the code for tabulate that calls the list for output

`topgn=(tabulate(alist, headers='keys',tablefmt='pipe',numalign='left',stralign='center'))`

Also attaching the screenshots [python output ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fsJ2k.png) - [discord bot ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WIx0e.jpg)

Thanks a ton

Comment: Unless you send it in a codeblock you won't be able to send it well formatted

Answer (score 0):

Use monospace font. Discord has codeblocks for this, which need 3 backticks.
So your code would be:

````
topgn = "```" + tabulate(alist, headers='keys',tablefmt='pipe',numalign='left',stralign='center') + "```"
````

Comment: thanks a lot. it worked. are there any other formatting tips for discord

Comment: @vieraaj [Here](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/210298617-Markdown-Text-101-Chat-Formatting-Bold-Italic-Underline) are all styles in Discord. If the answer was helpful, please click the checkmark at the left.